# How do I Connect to a Sybase Database from Windows CE using .Net?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce, sqlanywhere

I need to make a connection to a Sybase (SQL Anywhere) database in a Windows CE app over the network (wifi).

I'm hoping someone in the SO community has done before and can't point me in the right direction.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of information on the topic.  I've tried google, SO and the sybase website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your Connection String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere Namespace](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.php#http%3A%2F%2Fdcx.sybase.com%2F1101en%2Fdbprogramming_en11%2Fsqlanywhere-dotnet-2-0.html) from the [SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.php#http%3A//dcx.sybase.com/1101en/dbprogramming_en11/adodotnet-development-secta-3832474.html)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Workaround:

i'm not sure if it's feasible for you or not but if all else fails you could create a simple web service with one or two methods that accept SQL commands and return DataSets. It is a bigger IT hassle to have such a component in place between you clients and your sever but it does work. i did something similar a while back to communicate with an Oracle db.

Comment: There is no OLEDB provider for Sybase (or any other database) for Windows CE.  The link you point to is the desktop provider for SQL Server Compact - not at all what the question is asking for.

Comment: my bad ctacke. i wasn't paying very close attention. i edited the answer to just keep the workaround.